# on every launch of android application, it creates new instances of variables?

Tags: android

I am creating an application in which I want it to beep on change of some preset value accelerometer when toggle switch is on.

But the problem is, if I exit from app when toggle switch is on, and on next launch It beeps twice, and beeps once even if toggle switch is off.

How can I get rid of this issue?

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                if(flg1==false)
                {
                    stat.setText("Status: ON");
                    flg1=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    stat.setText("Status : OFF");
                    flg1=false;
                }

            }
        });




//
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


        deltaX = event.values[0];
        deltaY = event.values[1];
        deltaZ = event.values[2];

//after some changes to delta values


            if(flg1==true &&(deltaX>=Thresh||deltaY>=Thresh||deltaY>=Thresh))
            {
                if(mp1.isPlaying())
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
                else
                {
                    mp1.start();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "playing beep", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to remember the state of the toggle between application launches?

Comment: You might want to read about [persistent data](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). Specifically, I think the Shared Preferences "key-value pair primitive data" is what you need: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: Thank u all.. shared pref solved it....